# how to Configure jira Webhooks to hit a HTTPS URL

Tags: jira, webhooks, jenkins-jira-trigger

When I try to configure a webhook with https URL (say a [Jenkins endpoint](https://myjenkins.mycompany.com) ), I don't see the endpoint getting hit / the job that I configured with Jira trigger plugin is not triggered.

But the same webhook worked with HTTP protocol and I saw endpoints being hit.

Any suggestions on this behavior/ any links related this would be helpful (Especially with https protocol?

Comment: It's worth checking your JIRA server log (I assume you're not on JIRA cloud as it only supports HTTPS endpoint). Maybe it's because you're using a self-signed SSL certificate?

Comment: Hi Ceilfors. Thank you for thes response. Jira Cloud is what I use. How do we connect from jira cloud to hit a jenkins endpoint thats behind firwall

Comment: That is beyond what I can support unfortunately. I'll talk to your IT or anyone who's controlling the firewall and see what are the options to allow that traffic.

Comment: Sure . If anything has to be opened on firewall end or any configuration to be done . Please let me know. Would be helpful

Comment: Yes, the endpoint will has to be opened, just like any other HTTP server that you are trying to open up to the internet, while keeping a note on the security aspect of things. I'd again advise you to talk to your IT on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it too late but I had the same "issue". Jira doesn't support self-signed certificates for HTTPS
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-registering-webhooks-with-non-secure-urls/